# Whats wrong with this nearest neighbor algorithm for image scaling?

Tags: image-processing, rust, nearest-neighbor

I've been hunkered for days trying to find out what's wrong with my nearest neighbor interpolation when scaling an image half its size. Im using Rust but I don't think it matters as much as the algorithm:

```
/// Interpolate using nearest neighbor.
pub fn nearest(mut src: &mut Image, w2: i32, h2: i32) -> RasterResult<()> {

    // Compute scale
    let x_scale: f64 = src.width as f64 / w2 as f64;
    let y_scale: f64 = src.height as f64 / h2 as f64;

    // Create destination image
    let mut dest = Image::blank(w2, h2);

    // Loop thru destination image's pixels
    for y2 in 0..h2 {
        for x2 in 0..w2 {

            // Get location from src using nearest neighbor
            let x1: i32 = ( x2 as f64 * x_scale ).floor() as i32;
            let y1: i32 = ( y2 as f64 * y_scale ).floor() as i32;
            let pixel = try!(src.get_pixel(x1, y1));

            // Apply the pixels
            try!(dest.set_pixel(x2, y2, pixel));
        }
    }

    // Update the source image
    src.width = dest.width;
    src.height = dest.height;
    src.bytes = dest.bytes;

    Ok(())
}
```

My calling code:

```
// Open
let mut image = raster::open(r"test.png").unwrap();

// Resize to half
raster::interpolate::nearest(&mut image, 256, 128).unwrap();

// Save
raster::save(&image, r"out.png").unwrap();
```

It works fine for regular images but not on special cases. 
Here is the test image:
[image: test image]

Scaled to half with my code:

[image: scaled to half with my code]

For comparison here is Photoshop's:

[image: Scaled to half with Photoshop's]

I tested with GD and it yields similar results to Photoshop.

My investigation leads me to think that my computation of the source pixel (red squares) is off by one as compared to the others (green squares):

[image: zoom of problem area]

I also tried looking [into GD's source code](https://github.com/libgd/libgd/blob/00bbb69cc3fd7223e9fc7f01dd3d87c2956de93b/src/gd.c#L3229) to get a clue, but I don't fully understand what it does.

To clarify, I am not talking about using a different interpolation method such as bilinear and bicubic. I am comparing my nearest neighbor algorithm and its result to the result of Photoshop and GD's nearest neighbor algorithm. I am not asking why my results in Photoshop are ugly because I used nearest neighbor algorithm.

(Test image courtesy of Jonas Berlin via [Eric Brasseur](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112115812/http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma.html) )

Comment: You used a test image meant to show that simple scaling algorithms such as nearest neighbor are inadequate. And indeed it showed that. Everything is working as intended. If you want better results, use a better scaling algorithm.

Comment: @interjay - No. I think you misunderstand the question. I used nearest neighbor in Photoshop and GD and the results are different with my nearest neighbor algorithm. I am not asking for a different interpolation method.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly better way to do nearest neighbor interpolation is to make the interpolation go over the centers of the destination pixels instead of their top-left corner. In your code, that means adding `0.5` to `x2` and `y2` when calculating `x1` and `y1`.

```
let x1: i32 = ( (x2 as f64 + 0.5) * x_scale ).floor() as i32;
let y1: i32 = ( (y2 as f64 + 0.5) * y_scale ).floor() as i32;
```

When you scale by 1/2 this doesn't necessarily give a better result: each destination pixel is chosen from a 2x2 source area, so it doesn't matter which source pixel you choose. But when scaling by 1/3 this means that you choose the center of a 3x3 area instead of the top-left, which is better.

Photoshop probably uses a method like this, which is why you see different results.

Note that even if this makes the test image appear to scale better, another test image can be made that would look bad with the new algorithm. Offsetting your test image by (1,1) will probably do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm isn't wrong, necessarily. It depends on how you choose to define your coordinates. The requested scaling is a halving of the image resolution, which means there are four pixels to consider for each target pixel; they're equidistant, covering a quarter of each target pixel, so "nearest" isn't a useful metric to make the choice. You could still claim nearest neighbour even if the choice was random per pixel, but that would be a poor implementation because it would use a noisy distribution.

The image in this case is designed to show off which choice was actually made. Some rescaling procedures have made remarkable choices, in particular some versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer, and it can lead to weird biases.

For instance, in VIPS, if I apply nearest neighbour downscaling to the image I get your result (biased to the darker pixels), but if I apply a one pixel diagonal offset first (by choosing an odd offset region) I get the Photoshop result (biased to the lighter pixels). This is merely a result of rounding 0.5 up or down. You can get either to be more correct by defining where subpixel coordinates hit, that is, if a given pixel's coordinates is in a corner or center of that pixel.

The image appears to be designed to test not nearest neighbour, but gamma calculations for linear interpolation. Many image scalers incorrectly assume that the colour space is linear and straight average of pixel values can be used, but our vision is roughly logarithmic, so popular colour spaces like sRGB use a gamma curve to approximate it better.

Comment: I want the algo to work similar as other image processing programs, preferably with photoshop and imagemagick. This is to not surprise users with the results being different than what these other libs do. Yes the test image is for gamma but I chose to use it here since it works well in highlighting this subtle problem. Thanks for the response.